# Is there such a thing as a standard library in R?

Tags: r, shared-libraries, standards

Almost every major programming language comes with a standard library. It seems that R doesn't. There is a huge number of custom packages at CRAN, but I couldn't find something that qualifies as "standard library". The `base` package seems to come close, but then there is also the `recommended` package and I couldn't find consensus which one come closest to what one would call "standard library".

Comment: There is a set that any R installation comes with ["out of the box"](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-FAQ.html#Which-add_002don-packages-exist-for-R_003f). These are the [standard packages](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.html#Standard-packages). Do a clean install of R, start it up, and type `sessionInfo()`. You'll see stats, graphics, grDevices, utils, datasets, methods and base. Those are the only "standard" ones that are loaded by default, but R comes with the list I linked to.

Comment: But "loaded at the start" is not synonymous with "standard library". E.g. C++ has an extensive standard library, but you still have to import stuff if you want to use it. Is there no standard library in R in the sense that the core developers put all the functionality they consider essential for R in a curated library and call that "standard library", as is the case for, e.g. C++ or Python? Is all that is displayed by `sessionInfo()` also maintained by the core R developers?

Comment: I didn't say the loaded packages were the "standard library", I said they were loaded by default. That's all. The "standard" ones are merely the ones R comes with, as I said. You could quibble about whether the recommended packages count as part of a "standard library", but I don't think silly semantic arguments like that shed much light on anything. Those packages are recommended, and will be in binary installations, but maybe not source installations of R.

Comment: The "recommended" package may be the virtual Debian/Ubuntu package pulling in all the packages of priority Recommend as per the other comments and answers. The experienced R users are telling you about the actual packages pulled in by it.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel I can't quite follow you, could you please explain a bit more what you mean by a "virtual" package?

Comment: What is the recommended package you see? I was trying to explain to you that there is no package called "Recommended" at CRAN -- but some maintainers like myself created something with that name (or similar) which bring in packages "boot", "class", "cluster", ... "survival".  Makes sense?

Comment: Yes, there i. https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/doc/html/packages.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Bill Dunlap shared code for how to identify all of the packages that come with the standard distribution of your version of R.

```
i <- installed.packages() 
i[ i[,"Priority"] %in% c("base","recommended"), c("Package", "Priority")]
```

The "recommended" packages are shipped with R, but not loaded when R starts.

Edited to include a comment from joran: "Those packages are recommended, and will be in binary installations, but maybe not source installations of R."

Ref: http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/List-of-default-packages-that-come-with-R-td4661857.html

### Result for R 3.4.1

```
           Package      Priority     
base       "base"       "base"       
boot       "boot"       "recommended"
class      "class"      "recommended"
cluster    "cluster"    "recommended"
codetools  "codetools"  "recommended"
compiler   "compiler"   "base"       
datasets   "datasets"   "base"       
foreign    "foreign"    "recommended"
graphics   "graphics"   "base"       
grDevices  "grDevices"  "base"       
grid       "grid"       "base"       
KernSmooth "KernSmooth" "recommended"
lattice    "lattice"    "recommended"
MASS       "MASS"       "recommended"
Matrix     "Matrix"     "recommended"
methods    "methods"    "base"       
mgcv       "mgcv"       "recommended"
nlme       "nlme"       "recommended"
nnet       "nnet"       "recommended"
parallel   "parallel"   "base"       
rpart      "rpart"      "recommended"
spatial    "spatial"    "recommended"
splines    "splines"    "base"       
stats      "stats"      "base"       
stats4     "stats4"     "base"       
survival   "survival"   "recommended"
tcltk      "tcltk"      "base"       
tools      "tools"      "base"       
utils      "utils"      "base"
```

Comment: This is awesome! Are any other packages besides `base` or `recommended` shipped with R (but potentially not loaded at the start)?

Comment: Nope.  The priority column of `i` is either `base`, which is loaded at start, `recommended`, which is installed but not loaded, or `NA`, which means the user installed it from some other source (ie, CRAN, Github, Bioconductor, etc)

Comment: *grid* is in the "base" list, yet it needs to be loaded. Anybody knows why?

Comment: Maybe it is because it is a recent addition and they didn't want to change what gets loaded by default. But then, why was it not added to the "recommended" list then? I am a bit confused.